# Select all columns from table where one field is duplicated

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get a list of users (all their data) that have a duplicated email. 
I can get all the emails by using

```
SELECT EMAIL, Count(*) 
FROM USER_TABLE
Group By EMAIL having COUNT(*) > 1
```

and that returns a table of emails and their count (greater than 1).

I could write a query and just do

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_TABLE 
WHERE EMAIL IN ('dup@email.com', 'dup2@email.com' ...);`
```

but that requires me to always run the first query first and then copy paste them all into the `IN` statement.

What's the best way to combine these? Well not really combine, I don't care how many duplicates there are, I just want all the user info for users that have a duplicate email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much wrote the whole solution yourself. You just need your first query as the IN instead of hard coded list.

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_TABLE 
WHERE EMAIL IN
(
    SELECT EMAIL
    FROM USER_TABLE
    GROUP By EMAIL 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: LOL we had the same answer almost exactly at the same time. :)

Comment: Thanks! that worked! I figured it would be something like that but couldn't get the `Where` clause right. I'll mark this as accepted after the 10 minutes is up

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for the edit, is there a 'guideline' for when to use just the ticks how I had it originally and when to make it a block section of code?

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line. backticks are for when you want highlight something like  `SomeTableName`

Answer (score 1):

With window function COUNT:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        u.*,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY u.Email) AS Cnt
    FROM USER_TABLE u
) AS t
WHERE t.Cnt > 1
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I thnik, all solutions will look the same. A matter of taste

Answer (score 0):

We can also try self joining the `USER_TABLE` table to your first original query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM USER_TABLE t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT EMAIL 
    FROM USER_TABLE
    GROUP BY EMAIL
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.EMAIL = t2.EMAIL
```